# SEO: h1 & h2 - what should go into them?

Tags: seo, html, h1

I am still not quite sure today what should I put in H1 and H2 for SEO.

For instance, should my site title be H1 and my article title be H2?

```
<head>
    <title>My First Post - Another WordPress Website</title>
</head>

<h1>Another WordPress Website</h1>

<h2>My First Post</h2>
<p>brah brah brah</p>
<p>brah brah brah</p>
```

Or:

```
<head>
    <title>My First Post - Another WordPress Website</title>
</head>

<p>Another WordPress Website</p>

<h1>My First Post</h1>
<p>brah brah brah</p>
<p>brah brah brah</p>
```

Which is better?

Comment: `<span>Another WordPress Website</span>` or `<header>`, `<div>` etc would be better fitting Since p defines a paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally go with something like `<span>`, `<header>` or `<div>` but there's no right or wrong, or better in terms of SEO.

You are not going to see much difference in any of my examples or yours. Markup plays little role in actual ranking power. If H1 is used on site name then Google will establish h2 as the main page title. Too many webmasters are guilty of spending far too much over-thinking the markup.

Google, Bing and your visitors see the end result, not the source. So their stance is, who cares as long as it works.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to slightly disagree with Simon Hayter's response. **HTML markup** plays an important role determining the structural hierarchy of the webpage information. Also helps determine the website truthfulness, whether is delivering or not a good user experience.

The reason why the general advise is to code/write for the user (no for bots) is because each HTML tag represent an element with an **specific purpose** for the end user.

That being said the **`<title>`** tag will help the user decide whether or not to click on your listing in SERP. This will definitely impact your SEO, because if people is not clicking on your listing, Search Engines will decide not to show your webpage in the SERP.

Then, `<title>` tag and meta "description" need to be aligned with the content of your webpage and here is when/why `<H1>` and html markup in general plays an important role.

**What I recommend you to do**

Make sure your `<title>` is aligned with the content or the purpose of your webpage and at the same time is designed to encourage people to click through.

Use either `<H1>` or `<H2>` to get the user attention about the  webpage value proposition and make sure to include your main keyword at the start

I will also suggest using `<H3>` with a variation of your main keyword

**Which one is better?**

If "Another WordPress Website" if your brand or blog name I will use your second option:

```
<head>
    <title>My First Post - Another WordPress Website</title>
</head>

<p>Another WordPress Website</p>

<h1>My First Post</h1>
<p>brah brah brah</p>
<p>brah brah brah</p>
```